# How do I get the 4 digit user ID of a discord user?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I’m wondering how I can get the 4 digit user ID of a discord user from a message. For example, PruinaTempestatis#8487. Can someone help me?

Comment: I don’t want to mention the user, just say their info.

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: For example, if someone said a command, I would like to get their Username#4DigitID without mentioning the person.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the number always appears after a single hash `#` then you can simply do a split on that string and get the second value of the array like this:

**USING SPLIT**

```js
var str = 'PruinaTempestatis#8487';
var digits = str.split('#')[1];
console.log(digits);
```

**USING REGEX**

```js
var str = 'PruinaTempestatis#8487';
var digits = str.replace( /^\D+/g, '');
console.log(digits);
```

**USING SUBSTRING**

```js
var str = 'PruinaTempestatis#8487';
var digits = str.substr(str.indexOf('#')+1, str.length);
console.log(digits);
```

Comment: What if they have a hashtag in their name?

Comment: like what? Can you give an example @PruinaTempestatis

Comment: I want a way to get the ID without knowing it at first.

Comment: Something like msg.author.4 digit ID

Comment: What do you mean by `without knowing it at first`? @PruinaTempestatis

Comment: I am still not getting this

Comment: msg.author.id gives me the client ID, but I want the user ID.

Comment: Try console.log on msg.author to check other properties. Then once you found it, use str.split('#')[str.split('#').length-1] to get everything after the last hashtag

Comment: Thank you laurens

Comment: That what my answer has @PruinaTempestatis

Comment: It was called discriminator, discriminator held the 4 digit ID.

Comment: For your code to work, you had know the user’s user ID. I was trying to figure out thr ID.

Answer (score 1):

Using user.tag

```
message.channel.send(message.user.tag)
```

Answer (score 0):

Split their tag into an array and get the last element.

```
member.user.tag.split('#')[-1];
```

Comment: Code only answers can generally be improved by adding some explanation of how and why they work.